# SQL Drop Default Contraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I want to use the same command to drop the default value from a column, both from a sql compact and sql express database.

I know this works for SQL Compact:
`ALTER TABLE Person ALTER COLUMN CreatedDate DROP DEFAULT` and this for SQL Express: `ALTER TABLE Person DROP CONSTRAINT [DF_Person_CreatedDate]`.

Is there a common command that works both in SQL Compact 3.5 and SQL Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently not, the documentation clearly shows that ALTER TABLE has completely different syntax for [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) and [SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174123.aspx). I assume you will either have to handle this in your own program/script/whatever, or looks for a third-party tool or library that hides these differences.